# how to get pdf file size after generating using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

how to get PDF file size.? I am passing direct pdf url ..any idea? please

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo("C:\\file.txt");
FileAttributes attributes = info.Attributes;
Console.WriteLine(attributes);
info = new FileInfo("C:\\");
```

in above code iam not getting file info.. SO please give me idea how to get pdf file size?

Comment: Before asking any question you should have a look at the msdn [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileInfo.aspx) first

Answer (score 3):

Try this, will return the file size in bytes

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo("PDF file path");
long size = info.Length
```

Comment: Just a thought, but I think the OP wants to get the PDF size off a URL, not off the file system.  Meaning he'd have to d/l it first. Could be wrong tho...

Comment: instead of the d/l could ask the server using a HEAD request and let it tell you the size.

Answer (score 0):

To get file size in C#, you use:

```
long fileSize = (new FileInfo(fileName)).Length;
```

Is this not working?